# What variable to use in Java declaration

Tags: java, variables

What's the best variable to use while prompting a user to insert a symbol using the scanner class?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class characterSquare
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print( "Please enter a symbol");
        'x' = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.print( 'x', 'x', 'x' ,'x', 'x');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()), `Scanner.nextLine()` returns a `String`. Therefore, your variable must be declared as a string.

```
String x = sc.nextLine();
System.out.print(x, x, x, x, x);
```